# Shiny isolate - How not to send the hidden conditional input data to the server?

Tags: html, r, shiny

How can I ask Shiny **not** to send the **hidden** conditional input data to the server from the Shiny UI?

I have this problem which I don't know how to solve it.

When I select 'One site' and the dropdown **select options** for the site 2 will be **hidden** and I **don't** want any of the **site 2** data to be sent to the server.

But Shiny does send the hidden input data to the server **when I hit the GO button**. How can I not to send it?

Below are my code,

ui.R,

```
# Site 1 options.   
site1 <- selectInput(
    inputId = "site1",
    label = "Select a first site:",
    choices = c('1a', '1b')
)

# Site 2 options.
site2 <- selectInput(
    inputId = "site2",
    label = "Select a second site:",
    choices = c('2a', '2b')
)

shinyUI(
    pageWithSidebar(
        headerPanel("Shiny App"),
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(
                "distribution", 
                "Please select a type:", 
                choices = c("Both sites", "One site")
            ),

            # Site select input.
            site1,

            # Condition when the plot is a line plot.   
            conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.distribution == 'Both sites'",
                site2
            ),     
            actionButton("goButton", "Go!")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("myPlot")
        )
    )
)
```

server.R,

```
shinyServer( 
    function(input, output, session) {
        output$myPlot = renderPlot({

            # Take a dependency on input$goButton
            input$goButton

            site1 <- isolate(input$site1)
            site2 <- isolate(input$site2)

            plot(1, 1, col = "white")
            text(1, 1, paste(site1, " ", site2))
        })
    } 
)
```

Here are the visual:

two sites (correct result),

[image]

one site (**incorrect** result),

[image]

the expected result,

[image]

Any ideas? Is it a bug from Shiny?

Comment: Isn't a simple `text(1, 1, if (isolate(input$distribution)=="Both sites") paste(site1, " ", site2) else site1)` enough for your purpose?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Let me try this on my complex app to see this simple if-condition works or not. thanks!